# Return filtered API data in JavaScript after making dropdown selections?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The goal of Project is to select a state (hard coded), select activitie(s) you're interested in, and render the National Parks images and names based on the info selected. I'm stuck on what to do next to render the filtered National Parks. Would I add onto the existing `fetch()` or create a separate one? I currently have an alert set up when we click the button just to see that it's grabbing the state and activities. Would I replace that with a function?

```
// Assign API URL to a constant
const url = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?&api_key=wSlcKl1LSOpHXf164FTShbQZC4cmu1VWTJiipnFk&limit=500'

// Activities Dropdown
const acsDrop = document.getElementById('activities-dropdown')
acsDrop.length = 0

const acsDropDefault = document.createElement('option')
acsDropDefault.text = 'How do you wander?'

acsDrop.add(acsDropDefault)
acsDrop.selectedIndex = 0

// Fetch API and Render Activities
fetch(url)  
  .then(res => res.json().then(parks => {  
    let option
    for (let i = 0; i < parks.data.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < parks.data.length; j++) {
            option = document.createElement('option')
            option.text = parks.data[i].activities[j].name
            option.value = parks.data[i].activities[j].name
            acsDrop.add(option)
        }
    }    
  })
)  
// Catch Block
.catch(err => {  
    console.error('Fetch Error', err)
    })


// Click Event Listener and Activities Selected
const wanderBtn = document.getElementById('submit')

const letsWander = wanderBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const selectedState = document.getElementById('states-dropdown')
    const checkedActivity = document.querySelectorAll('#activities-dropdown :checked')
    const selected = [...checkedActivity, selectedState].map(option => option.value)
    alert(selected)
})
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div>
    <select id="states-dropdown" name="states">
      <option selected disabled>Where will you wander?</option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
      <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
      <option value="CA">California</option>
      <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
      <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
      <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
      <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
      <option value="FL">Florida</option>
      <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
      <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
      <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
      <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
      <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
      <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
      <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
      <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
      <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
      <option value="ME">Maine</option>
      <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
      <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
      <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
      <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
      <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
      <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
      <option value="MT">Montana</option>
      <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
      <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
      <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
      <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
      <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
      <option value="NY">New York</option>
      <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
      <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
      <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
      <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
      <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
      <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
      <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
      <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
      <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
      <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="TX">Texas</option>
      <option value="UT">Utah</option>
      <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
      <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
      <option value="WA">Washington</option>
      <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
      <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>    
    </select>
    <select id="activities-dropdown" name="activities" multiple="multiple"> 
    </select>       
    <button id="submit">Let's Wander!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="park-results">

    </div>
```

sample of JSON data

```
{
    "id": "77E0D7F0-1942-494A-ACE2-9004D2BDC59E",
    "url": "https://www.nps.gov/abli/index.htm",
    "fullName": "Abraham Lincoln Birthplace National Historical Park",
    "parkCode": "abli",
    "description": "For over a century people from around the world have come to rural Central Kentucky to honor the humble beginnings of our 16th president, Abraham Lincoln. His early life on Kentucky's frontier shaped his character and prepared him to lead the nation through Civil War. The country's first memorial to Lincoln, built with donations from young and old, enshrines the symbolic birthplace cabin.",
    "latitude": "37.5858662",
    "longitude": "-85.67330523",
    "latLong": "lat:37.5858662, long:-85.67330523",
    "activities": [{
        "id": "13A57703-BB1A-41A2-94B8-53B692EB7238",
        "name": "Astronomy"
    }, {
        "id": "D37A0003-8317-4F04-8FB0-4CF0A272E195",
        "name": "Stargazing"
    }, {
        "id": "1DFACD97-1B9C-4F5A-80F2-05593604799E",
        "name": "Food"
    }, {
        "id": "C6D3230A-2CEA-4AFE-BFF3-DC1E2C2C4BB4",
        "name": "Picnicking"
    }, {
        "id": "DF4A35E0-7983-4A3E-BC47-F37B872B0F25",
        "name": "Junior Ranger Program"
    }, {
        "id": "0B685688-3405-4E2A-ABBA-E3069492EC50",
        "name": "Wildlife Watching"
    }, {
        "id": "5A2C91D1-50EC-4B24-8BED-A2E11A1892DF",
        "name": "Birdwatching"
    }, {
        "id": "24380E3F-AD9D-4E38-BF13-C8EEB21893E7",
        "name": "Shopping"
    }, {
        "id": "467DC8B8-0B7D-436D-A026-80A22358F615",
        "name": "Bookstore and Park Store"
    }, {
        "id": "43800AD1-D439-40F3-AAB3-9FB651FE45BB",
        "name": "Gift Shop and Souvenirs"
    }],
    "topics": [{
        "id": "D10852A3-443C-4743-A5FA-6DD6D2A054B3",
        "name": "Birthplace"
    }, {
        "id": "F669BC40-BDC4-41C0-9ACE-B2CD25373045",
        "name": "Presidents"
    }, {
        "id": "0D00073E-18C3-46E5-8727-2F87B112DDC6",
        "name": "Animals"
    }, {
        "id": "957EF2BD-AC6C-4B7B-BD9A-87593ADC6691",
        "name": "Birds"
    }, {
        "id": "E25F3456-43ED-45DD-93BC-057F9B944F7A",
        "name": "Caves, Caverns and Karst"
    }, {
        "id": "F0F97E32-2F29-41B4-AF98-9FBE8DAB36B1",
        "name": "Geology"
    }, {
        "id": "4BE01DC5-52E6-4F18-8C9A-B22D65965F6D",
        "name": "Groundwater"
    }, {
        "id": "0E1A04CC-EB51-4F18-93D4-EC0B0B4EC1E3",
        "name": "Freshwater Springs"
    }, {
        "id": "A7359FC4-DAD8-45F5-AF15-7FF62F816ED3",
        "name": "Night Sky"
    }],
    "states": "KY",
    "contacts": {
        "phoneNumbers": [{
            "phoneNumber": "2703583137",
            "description": "",
            "extension": "",
            "type": "Voice"
        }, {
            "phoneNumber": "2703583874",
            "description": "",
            "extension": "",
            "type": "Fax"
        }],
        "emailAddresses": [{
            "description": "",
            "emailAddress": "ABLI_Administration@nps.gov"
        }]
    },
    "entranceFees": [{
        "cost": "0.00",
        "description": "There is no fee associated with visiting either unit of the park.",
        "title": "Fee Free Park"
    }],
    "entrancePasses": [],
    "fees": [],
    "directionsInfo": "The Birthplace Unit of the park is located approximately 2 miles south of the town of Hodgenville on U.S. Highway 31E South. The Boyhood Home Unit at Knob Creek is located approximately 10 miles northeast of the Birthplace Unit of the park.",
    "directionsUrl": "http://www.nps.gov/abli/planyourvisit/directions.htm",
    "operatingHours": [{
        "exceptions": [{
            "exceptionHours": {},
            "startDate": "2022-01-01",
            "name": "Park is Closed",
            "endDate": "2022-01-01"
        }, {
            "exceptionHours": {},
            "startDate": "2021-11-25",
            "name": "Park is Closed",
            "endDate": "2021-11-25"
        }, {
            "exceptionHours": {},
            "startDate": "2021-12-25",
            "name": "Park is Closed",
            "endDate": "2021-12-25"
        }],
        "description": "The Memorial Building is open 9:00 am - 4:30 pm eastern time with a limited viewing area.  The Visitor Center and grounds of the Birthplace Unit are open 9:00 am - 5:00 pm eastern time with one-way traffic flow and social distancing.\n\n\nThe Boyhood Home Unit at Knob Creek will be closed August 3, 2020, to July 31, 2021, due to the Lincoln Tavern Rehabilitation Project.",
        "standardHours": {
            "wednesday": "9:00AM - 5:00PM",
            "monday": "9:00AM - 5:00PM",
            "thursday": "9:00AM - 5:00PM",
            "sunday": "9:00AM - 5:00PM",
            "tuesday": "9:00AM - 5:00PM",
            "friday": "9:00AM - 5:00PM",
            "saturday": "9:00AM - 5:00PM"
        },
        "name": "Abraham Lincoln Birthplace National Historical Park"
    }],
    "addresses": [{
        "postalCode": "42748",
        "city": "Hodgenville",
        "stateCode": "KY",
        "line1": "2995 Lincoln Farm Road",
        "type": "Physical",
        "line3": "",
        "line2": ""
    }, {
        "postalCode": "42748",
        "city": "Hodgenville",
        "stateCode": "KY",
        "line1": "2995 Lincoln Farm Road",
        "type": "Mailing",
        "line3": "",
        "line2": ""
    }],
    "images": [{
        "credit": "NPS Photo",
        "title": "The Memorial Building with fall colors",
        "altText": "The Memorial Building surrounded by fall colors",
        "caption": "Over 200,000 people a year come to walk up the steps of the Memorial Building to visit the site where Abraham Lincoln was born",
        "url": "https://www.nps.gov/common/uploads/structured_data/3C861078-1DD8-B71B-0B774A242EF6A706.jpg"
    }, {
        "credit": "NPS Photo",
        "title": "The Memorial Building",
        "altText": "The first memorial erected to honor Abraham Lincoln",
        "caption": "The Memorial Building constructed on the traditional site of the birth of Abraham Lincoln.",
        "url": "https://www.nps.gov/common/uploads/structured_data/3C861263-1DD8-B71B-0B71EF9B95F9644F.jpg"
    }, {
        "credit": "NPS Photo",
        "title": "The Symbolic Birth Cabin of Abraham Lincoln",
        "altText": "The symbolic birth cabin on the traditional site of the birth of Abraham Lincoln.",
        "caption": "The symbolic birth cabin of Abraham Lincoln.",
        "url": "https://www.nps.gov/common/uploads/structured_data/3C86137D-1DD8-B71B-0B978BACD7EBAEF1.jpg"
    }, {
        "credit": "NPS Photo",
        "title": "Statue of the Lincoln Family in the Visitor Center",
        "altText": "Statue of the Lincoln family in the park's Visitor Center",
        "caption": "Visitors to the park can view the statue of the Lincoln family.",
        "url": "https://www.nps.gov/common/uploads/structured_data/3C8614D1-1DD8-B71B-0B1AF72CA452B051.jpg"
    }],
    "weatherInfo": "There are four distinct seasons in Central Kentucky. However, temperature and weather conditions can vary widely within those seasons. Spring and Fall are generally pleasant with frequent rain showers. Summer is usually hot and humid. Winter is moderately cold with mixed precipitation.",
    "name": "Abraham Lincoln Birthplace",
    "designation": "National Historical Park"
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is just one park. It's not clear what you want to show when they select an activity.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I was just stating an example of what the JSON looks like instead copying all the data over. I am trying to show the following when they select the state and activity: image, fullName

Comment: Is the actual JSON an array of those objects?

Comment: Assign `parks` to a global variable. Then when they select something from the menus, you can search the variable for the information you want to display.

Comment: @barmar it is yes

Comment: You're going to get lots of duplicate activities in the activities dropdown.

Comment: So I would just assign the fetch to a constant called parks? and then how do I search the variable

Comment: my activities dropdown currently works using all the data. It lists each activity once. There are 10 activities

Comment: The same way you create the options, with nested loops. But in this case you search for matches to the menu selections.

Comment: If multiple parks have the same activity, I don't see how you prevent adding that activity multiple times to the dropdown.